# Silverlight Binding path to element

Tags: xaml, silverlight, binding, esri

I'm having problem binding to correct object. How do I construct such path?

[image]

I'm binding Esri Silverlight control Graphic's layer to collection of `TrackedAsset` objects.
Now, inside graphics template I'm trying to bind to property of this `TrackedAsset` object.

It fails and this is what I see under locals. Seems like default binding inside of esri graphics points to ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.DataBinding object. This object has collection of "Attributes" and value of first of those attributes happen to be object I need.

I tried: {Binding Attributes.Values[0].IsGPSDataRecent}, no binding errors but I see no getter executed and it doesn't work as expected..

Comment: I believe the binding would break if "Attributes" was null, or if "Values" was empty initially -- maybe that's the problem?  I would try using a converter, as in `Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DataToBrushConverter}}"`.  At the very least that would help with debugging.

Comment: Thats a good idea!! I might just create converter for DataToTrackedAsset and see. I want to keep existing code base same if possible. Also seems like Esri control is extremely bad about MVVM support.

Comment: Why don't you add a boolean property to your ViewModel and bind against it ? If the object array is not null, return it; otherwise return false.

Comment: In my experience, you are right: Esri controls support for MVVM is patchy at best. With regards to your particular problem, does `Values[0]` really then have a property called `IsGPSDataRecent` within it? With the Key/Value pairs structure I'd expect `Value[0]` to be a value, not a class/struct.

Comment: Ok, it seems like there is too much to deal with. I almost got to the point of passing reference to map control to my VM. I guess I will make subclass of Esri control, handle graphics, etc in code (in sublcass) and then use my control. Also works - behaviours, bindings, etc made to some specific use cases which is not what we do.